# Docfx failing on init command

Tags: docfx

I am trying to get docfx to generate a doc website based off of a C# library and I can't seem to get any of the commands covered in the documentation to work.

On the [quickstart](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx_getting_started.html) page it states to use the following command to initialize a template `docfx init -q` however when I run this command I get the following error message:

```
'init' was not matched. Did you mean 'new'?
'-q' was not matched. Did you mean '-h'?
Required command was not provided.
Unrecognized command or argument 'init'
Unrecognized command or argument '-q'

Usage:
  docfx [options] [command]

Options:
  --version         Show version information
  -?, -h, --help    Show help and usage information

Commands:
  new <templateName>     Creates a new docset.
  restore <directory>    Restores dependencies before build.
  build <directory>      Builds a docset.
  serve <directory>      Serves content in a docset.
```

The documentation (as far as I can tell) doesn't cover the options displayed by the tools output. I have checked a number of times now to make sure I am not going insane but I definitely downloaded the package from the page listed on the quickstart [page](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/releases).

Does anyone regularly use Docfx and can tell me how to go about generating the html for my library?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using 3.x, which is undocumented.
You can download 2.59.2 [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/releases/tag/v2.59.2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It seems that the recommended command `dotnet tool update -g docfx` will install version 3.*, but the syntax for this version differs from 2.*. I got the same errors, exchanged the files in `C:\Program Files\docfx` with the files of version 2.* and it worked again.